# How to sort dataframe without changing groupings in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to do a groupby using Pandas and apply a sort. Something like below:
[image: 1] I have so far created the individual frames to get the subtotals. Not sure how to proceed after that to get the sorting done properly without resorting to hacks.

Sample dataframe is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39955336/pandas-pivot-table-columns-order-and-subtotals) previous question.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'admin0': ['cntry1', 'cntry1', 'cntry1', 'cntry1', 'cntry1', 'cntry1', 'cntry2', 'cntry2', 'cntry2', 'cntry2', 'cntry2'], 
'admin1': ['state1', 'state1', 'state1', 'state2', 'state2', 'state2', 'state3', 'state3', 'state3', 'state3', 'state4'], 
'admin2': ['city1', 'city1', 'city2', 'city3', 'city4', 'city4', 'city5', 'city6', 'city6', 'city6', 'city7'], 
'windspeed': [60, 90, 60, 60, 60, 90, 60, 60, 90, 120, 60], 
'population': [700, 210, 100, 70, 180, 370, 890, 120, 420, 360, 740]
})
g1 = df.groupby(['admin0', 'admin1',  'admin2']).sum()
g2 = g1.groupby(level=[0, 1]).sum()
g2.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([g2.index.get_level_values(0), g2.index.get_level_values(1), len(g2.index)*['']])
g3 = g1.groupby(level=0).sum()
g3.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([g3.index.get_level_values(0), len(g3.index)*[''], len(g3.index)*['']])
g = pd.concat([g1, g2, g3])
```

State of g now:

```
                         windspeed  population
admin0 admin1 admin2                       
cntry1 state1 city1         150         910
              city2          60         100
       state2 city3          60          70
              city4         150         550
cntry2 state3 city5          60         890
              city6         270         900
       state4 city7          60         740
cntry1 state1               210        1010
       state2               210         620
cntry2 state3               330        1790
       state4                60         740
cntry1                      420        1630
cntry2                      390        2530
```

I now want to be able to sort without changing the grouping as shown in the gif.

Expected response when grouping by windspeed ascending:

```
                      windspeed  population
admin0 admin1 admin2
cntry2                      390        2530
       state4                60         740
              city7          60         740
       state3               330        1790
              city5          60         890
              city6         270         900
cntry1                      420        1630
       state1               210        1010
              city2          60         100
              city1         150         910
       state2               210         620
              city3          60          70
              city4         150         550
```

Comment: `g.sort_values('windspeed', ascending = False)`? same for 'population'?

Answer (score 0):

Example for ascending sort by `'windspeed'`, continuing from your dataframe `g`:

```
levels = ['admin0', 'admin1',  'admin2']
g.groupby(levels[:-1], group_keys = False).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by = 'windspeed', ascending=True))
```

Basically you need to perform groupby as you did, then groupby it again on all levels except the last one and apply a sort by a desired column.

Comment: Hi .. thanks for the response. I am not sure it matches what I am looking for.

Comment: I edited the answer, no need to single out a column, you can just pass it to the sort. Maybe this matches what you want better.

Comment: Sorry .. I am still learning how to answer properly with code/images in response. As you can see from the gif above, I still need to sort the group/suubgroup level totals in additions to the final leaf node.

Comment: Oh, I just looked at the input dataframe and missed the additional groupings you performed, sorry. I edited the answer so that it starts from your dataframe `g`, please check if this is what you want.

Comment: Nevermind, the sort doesn't seem to affect the totals, I see the issue now. Guess it needs sort of a workaround for the double groupby trick, just can't think of one right now.

Comment: This is precisely my issue. The hack I used was to introduce new column with a tuple with entry for each level. And I ended up sorting the mini dataframes, then assigning the new value, sort all over again. It is very time consuming for large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

**edit: after clarification on question, revising answer, original response below hline**

To sort values within a multi-index, just include the multi-index levels in the sort call. Sorting happens in order, so it sorts by the first key, then within that sorts the second key, and so on.:

```
>>> g.sort_values(['admin0', 'admin1', 'admin2', 'windspeed'])
                      windspeed  population
admin0 admin1 admin2                       
cntry1                      420        1630
       state1               210        1010
              city1         150         910
              city2          60         100
       state2               210         620
              city3          60          70
              city4         150         550
cntry2                      390        2530
       state3               330        1790
              city5          60         890
              city6         270         900
       state4                60         740
              city7          60         740
```

However in your example the `ascending=False` looks like this, which isn't exactly what you want, because of the way the multi-index was created with `''` blank strings for the 'country' and 'state'-level measurements:

```
>>> g.sort_values(['admin0', 'admin1', 'admin2', 'windspeed'], ascending=False)
                      windspeed  population
admin0 admin1 admin2                       
cntry2 state4 city7          60         740
                             60         740
       state3 city6         270         900
              city5          60         890
                            330        1790
                            390        2530
cntry1 state2 city4         150         550
              city3          60          70
                            210         620
       state1 city2          60         100
              city1         150         910
                            210        1010
                            420        1630
```

this might be sorta confusing, but it's because of the way pandas prints multiindexes -- when a level of a multi-index is repeated, it isn't printed again. but since the level values are set to `''` you can't tell when it's just not repeating them again vs. when the label is *actually `''`* You can get the exact output you want by using some character that comes after `state` or `city` , like for example if i replace `''` with `'z'` in the `MultiIndex.from_arrays` calls:

```
g.sort_values(['admin0', 'admin1', 'admin2', 'windspeed'], ascending=False)
                      windspeed  population
admin0 admin1 admin2                       
cntry2 z      z             390        2530
       state4 z              60         740
              city7          60         740
       state3 z             330        1790
              city6         270         900
              city5          60         890
cntry1 z      z             420        1630
       state2 z             210         620
              city4         150         550
              city3          60          70
       state1 z             210        1010
              city2          60         100
              city1         150         910
```

Or you could use an ordered categorical index where you explicitly specify that `''` should be the last (rather than the first) label.

---

**original answer**

I think I may be misunderstanding your question, is this not what you want?

```
>>> g.sort_values(by="windspeed")
                      windspeed  population
admin0 admin1 admin2                       
cntry1 state1 city2          60         100
       state2 city3          60          70
cntry2 state3 city5          60         890
       state4 city7          60         740
                             60         740
cntry1 state1 city1         150         910
       state2 city4         150         550
       state1               210        1010
       state2               210         620
cntry2 state3 city6         270         900
                            330        1790
                            390        2530
cntry1                      420        1630

>>> g.sort_values(by=["windspeed","population"])
                      windspeed  population
admin0 admin1 admin2                       
cntry1 state2 city3          60          70
       state1 city2          60         100
cntry2 state4 city7          60         740
                             60         740
       state3 city5          60         890
cntry1 state2 city4         150         550
       state1 city1         150         910
       state2               210         620
       state1               210        1010
cntry2 state3 city6         270         900
                            330        1790
                            390        2530
cntry1                      420        1630
>>>
```

Comment: yes .. sorting shouln't affect the grouping. The groups themselves should be together. In the response you included the groups are intermingled.

Comment: ok, @doomer i think i get the question now, edited my answer to answer it.

Comment: If we include all levels in the index in sort .. the result will be same as sorting index and the value columns have no impact. As you can see in the result, state 4 (total 60) comes before state 3 (330) where as city 5 (60) comes after city 6(270). So there is no sorting wrt to windspeed. I have posted an answer which is done using python. You can compare the result .. and ideally blank values in the index shouldnt have any impact. as they represent total of the subgroups and always show up at the node where group starts.

Comment: aha, i think i see what you mean at last -- in that case my answer is that the data is ill-formatted because you're doing several levels of comparison at once -- comparing apples to oranges in the same column. i would recommend reformatting the data to having a 'type' column that specifies what 'windspeed' means in each case (a city, state, or country count) because the implicit difference in blank labels is not doing what you need. i think you're mixing up 'model' with 'view' in this case -- you don't need to compute on your data in the form that you display it in.

Comment: but if your answer works for you, then great!

Comment: Not sure about view vs model here. I am simply sorting first by country totals which fixes their order.. then state totals with in countries (without changing the countries order previously set) .. and finally cities within states based on windspeed. It would be the most natural interpretation of sort in presence of groupings.

Comment: right, what i'm saying is that typically you wouldn't have them all together in the same dataframe like this, or else would have some column specifically indicating whether the 'value' corresponds to a city, state, etc. rather than implicitly labeling something as a 'state' by just having the 'county' and 'city' indices blank.

Answer (score 0):

Use sort_index(level=0)

```
                      windspeed  population
admin0 admin1 admin2                       
cntry1                      420        1630
       state1               210        1010
              city1         150         910
              city2          60         100
       state2               210         620
              city3          60          70
              city4         150         550
cntry2                      390        2530
       state3               330        1790
              city5          60         890
              city6         270         900
       state4                60         740
              city7          60         740
```

Comment: This is the default pandas sort where index is sorted (alphabetically in this case). Once I apply order to windspeed or population, it is messing up the order.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the first 3 columns in the sort

```
g1.sort_values(by=['admin0', 'admin1',  'admin2','windspeed','population'], ascending = False)
```

Comment: This is equivalent to pandas default sort without any consideration for the actual columns ie `windspeed` and `population`. Mini sorts should be done excluding the last level to preserve order. ie `g1.sort_values(by=['admin0', 'admin1', 'windspeed','population'], ascending = False), g2.sort_values(by=['admin0', 'windspeed','population'], ascending = False)` etc to have impact. There is still no easy way to combine these mini dfs

Answer (score 0):

This is my hacked solution. It is ugly and definitely bad due to excessive computation in python layer. Hope pandas/numpy/scipy experts can poke holes and give a better solution than this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def compute_glevels(mini_dfs, rp_len):

    level_vals = [{} for _ in range(rp_len)]
    for i, sdf in enumerate(reversed(mini_dfs)):
        idx = sdf.index
        g_levels = [[[] for _ in range(rp_len)] for _ in range(len(idx))]
        for j, entry in enumerate(sdf.index):
            for l, lv in enumerate(entry):
                if lv:
                    if l > i:
                        print('i', i,  'j', j, 'l', l, 'level_vals', level_vals)
                        raise Exception
                    else:
                        v = level_vals[l].setdefault(entry[:l+1], len(level_vals[l]) + 1)
                        g_levels[j][l] = v
                else:
                    g_levels[j][l] = 0
        sdf['g_lvl'] = g_levels


def run(df, row_pivots=None, aggregates=None, sort=None):

    rp_len = len(row_pivots)
    by = list(row_pivots[:-1])
    asc = [True] * (rp_len - 1)
    for entry in sort:
        by.append(entry[0])
        asc.append(entry[1] == 'asc')
    grouper = df.groupby(list(row_pivots), sort=False).agg(aggregates)
    grouper.sort_values(by=by, ascending=asc, inplace=True)
    sdfs = [grouper]

    for i in range(1, rp_len):
        if i < rp_len - 1:
            by = list(row_pivots[:-(i+1)])
            asc = [True] * len(by)
        else:
            by = []
            asc = []
        for entry in sort:
            by.append(entry[0])
            asc.append(entry[1] == 'asc')
        levels = list(range(rp_len - i))
        sdf = sdfs[i-1].groupby(level=levels, sort=False).agg(aggregates)
        sdf.sort_values(by=by, ascending=asc, inplace=True)
        idx_len = len(sdf.index)
        sdf.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([sdf.index.get_level_values(l) if l < (rp_len - i) else [''] * idx_len for l in range(rp_len)])
        sdfs.append(sdf)

    compute_glevels(sdfs, rp_len)
    total_dict = sdfs[-1].agg(aggregates).to_dict()
    total_dict['g_lvl'] = [0, 0, 0]
    total = pd.DataFrame([total_dict], columns=sdfs[0].columns, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([[''] * rp_len], names=row_pivots))
    sdfs.append(total)
    g = pd.concat(sdfs).sort_values('g_lvl')
    print(g)
    return g

if __name__ == '__main__':

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'admin0': ['cntry1', 'cntry1', 'cntry1', 'cntry1', 'cntry1', 'cntry1', 'cntry2', 'cntry2', 'cntry2', 'cntry2','cntry2'],
        'admin1': ['state1', 'state1', 'state1', 'state2', 'state2', 'state2', 'state3', 'state3', 'state3', 'state3','state4'],
        'admin2': ['city1', 'city1', 'city2', 'city3', 'city4', 'city4', 'city5', 'city6', 'city6', 'city6', 'city7'],
        'windspeed': [60, 90, 60, 60, 60, 90, 60, 60, 90, 120, 60],
        'population': [700, 210, 100, 70, 180, 370, 890, 120, 420, 360, 740]
    })
    g1 = run(df, row_pivots=('admin0', 'admin1', 'admin2'), aggregates={'windspeed': np.sum, 'population': np.sum}, sort=(('windspeed', 'asc'), ))
    g2 = run(df, row_pivots=('admin0', 'admin1', 'admin2'), aggregates={'windspeed': np.sum, 'population': np.sum}, sort=(('windspeed', 'asc'), ('population', 'asc')))
    print(g1.equals(g2))
```